# Windows 2008 on Sun Virtual Box

Tags: windows-server-2008

Does anyone else have problems running windows 2008 with Sun Virtual Box?

We get an error when we try installing Framework 3.5 SP1

Comment: No, and a little more explanation of what you want help with would be beneficial.

Comment: I've been using it for only a few months so I don't have any issues. Could you specify an issue/problem you have with it? If not, are you looking for recommendations?

Comment: Did you the .NET 3.5 Framework *first* or are you trying to install SP1 first?

Comment: Install of .net 3.5 Framework also fails

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't have any problems with Server 2008 on VirtualBox and had no problems getting it current with updates either.

Comment: Thanks, it does not fix the problem, but it confirms that it is not Virtual Box that it is causing the problem